# Proper use of dcast.table.table in a function

Tags: r, data.table

How do I embed a dcast.data.table() properly into a function?

I would like to write a function which uses (among other things) a dcast.data.table() command. One thing the function should do is to transform a data.frame into a data.table. After that, it should dcast the table.

Take for example this dataframe:

```
test <-data.frame(lett=c("a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "e"), 
                  group=c(1,1,1,3,3,4,4),
                  perc=sample(1:100,7))
  lett group perc
1    a     1   71
2    b     1   87
3    c     1   36
4    c     3   39
5    d     3    4
6    d     4   20
7    e     4   16
```

dcast.data.table works fine if not embedded in a function:

```
test.dt <- setDT(as.list(test))
dcast.data.table(test.dt, lett~group, var.value="perc")

Using 'perc' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
   lett  1  3  4
1:    a 71 NA NA
2:    b 87 NA NA
3:    c 36 39 NA
4:    d NA  4 20
5:    e NA NA 16
```

But when I embed the setDT(as.list()) and dcast.data.table in function, I get the error "Error in dcast.data.table.... Column 'y' not found".

```
myfunction <- function(d, y, z,v) 
                      {d <- setDT(as.list(d))
                      temp <- dcast.data.table(d, y~z, 
                                    value.var=v)
                      return(temp)}

myfunction(test)
```

Any hints would be appreciated.

## ------------------------------------------------------------------

My previous command had a mistake (I forgot to add the remaining arguments). I meant to write this:

```
myfunction(test,lett,group,perc)
```

Comment: What exactly do you save by doing this? You would still have to type out the dataset name, the LHS, the RHS, and the value variable. To get this to work you would have to construct and evaluate the formula inside your function.

Comment: `ddt <- function(dt, ...) dcast.data.table(if (!is.data.table(dt)) as.data.table(dt) else dt, ...)` Then, just use it the same way you would normally use `dcast.data.table`, whether or not the input is a `data.table`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function has problems, it takes 4 arguments, but you call it with only one.
This function, however, will work.

```
myfunction <- function(d) {
   d <- setDT(as.list(d))
   formula <- as.formula(paste(names(d)[1],"~",names(d)[2]))
   temp <- dcast.data.table(d, formula ,value.var=names(d)[3])
   return(temp)
}
```

Comment: I corrected my function above. Simply forgot to add the other arguments. * I liked the ansswer that @PeterK suggested but I wanted to have a function that is independent of index numbers, so that column names can be supplied, flexibly.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution to my problem:

```
myfunction <- function(d=NULL, y,z,v) 
{y<-eval(substitute(y),d, parent.frame())
 z<-eval(substitute(z),d, parent.frame())
 v<-eval(substitute(v),d, parent.frame())
 d.temp <- data.table(y=y,z=z,v=v)
 temp <- dcast.data.table(d.temp, y~z, 
                          value.var="v")
 return(temp)
}
myfunction(test, lett, group, perc)
```

Returns the desired output:

```
   y  1  3  4
1: a 14 NA NA
2: b 97 NA NA
3: c 93  9 NA
4: d NA 67 86
5: e NA NA 72
```